# Tensorflow: Recurrent Neural Network Batch Training

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement RNN in Tensorflow. I am writing my own functions instead of using RNN cells to practice.

The problem is sequence tagging, input size is [32, 48, 900] where 32 is batch size, 48 is time steps and 900 is vocab size which is one-hot encoded vector. Output is [32, 48, 145] where first two dimensions are same as input, but the last dimension is output vocabulary size (one-hot). Basically this is a NLP tagging problem.

I am getting following error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must
>   be same size: logits_size=[48,145] labels_size=[1536,145]

The actual labels_size is [32, 48, 145] but it merges first two dimensions without my control. FYI 32*48 = 1536

If I run my RNN with batch size 1, it works fine as expected. I could not figure out how to solve the issue. I am getting the problem in the last line of the code.

I pasted the related part of the code:

```
    inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, self.seq_length, self.vocab_size], dtype=tf.float32, name="inputs")
    targets = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, self.seq_length, self.output_vocab_size], dtype=tf.float32, name="targets")
    init_state = tf.placeholder(shape=[1, self.hidden_size], dtype=tf.float32, name="state")

    initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1)

    with tf.variable_scope("RNN") as scope:
        hs_t = init_state
        ys = []
        for t, xs_t in enumerate(tf.split(inputs[0], self.seq_length, axis=0)):
            if t > 0: scope.reuse_variables()
            Wxh = tf.get_variable("Wxh", [self.vocab_size, self.hidden_size], initializer=initializer)
            Whh = tf.get_variable("Whh", [self.hidden_size, self.hidden_size], initializer=initializer)
            Why = tf.get_variable("Why", [self.hidden_size, self.output_vocab_size], initializer=initializer)
            bh = tf.get_variable("bh", [self.hidden_size], initializer=initializer)
            by = tf.get_variable("by", [self.output_vocab_size], initializer=initializer)

            hs_t = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(xs_t, Wxh) + tf.matmul(hs_t, Whh) + bh)
            ys_t = tf.matmul(hs_t, Why) + by
            ys.append(ys_t)

    hprev = hs_t
    output_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(ys)  # Get softmax for sampling

    #outputs = tf.concat(ys, axis=0)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=targets, logits=ys))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may fall in the size of the ys, ys should have the size of  [32, 48, 145], but the output ys only have the size of [48,145], so if the batchsize is 1, the taget size is [1, 48, 145], which just have the same size of [48,145] after dimensionality reduction.

To solve the problem you can add a loop to deal with the batchsize ( inputs[0] ) :

such as :

```
for i in range(inputs.getshape(0)):
   for t, xs_t in enumerate(tf.split(inputs[i], self.seq_length, axis=0)):
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem, but syntax is like following: for i in range(inputs.get_shape()[0])